# How to compute"mean","sum" for matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

I have several matrices but for simplicity I provided only example.
Assume that we two matrices A and B.
I want to compute the mean  out of A and B

```
    A = matrix( 
c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), # the data elements 
     nrow=2,              # number of rows 
    ncol=3,              # number of columns 
    byrow = TRUE)  
  B = matrix( 
c(2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 8), # the data elements 
      nrow=2,              # number of rows 
      ncol=3,              # number of columns 
      byrow = TRUE)  
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    3
[2,]    1    5    7
> B
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    6
[2,]    1    4    8
```

So I want the mean:
this can be easily done like:

```
   A+B/2
```

but I have more than 100 matrices so I can not use this so i tried to use

```
   mat <- list(A, B)
   x<- do.call(rbind,(lapply(mat,FUN = mean)))
```

But this computed the mean for each matrix:

```
     > x
        [,1]
  [1,]    6
  [2,]    6
```

Any  ides?

Comment: What is your desired output? Also check out `mget` to put your matrices in a list. Do they follow a named pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following work for your needs?

Use `Reduce` to add the `list` of matrices together.

```
X <- list(A, B)
Reduce("+", X)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    8    9
# [2,]    2    9   15
```

Divide the output by the `length` of the `list`.

```
Reduce("+", X)/length(X)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2  4.0  4.5
# [2,]    1  4.5  7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful

```
> # your list of matrices
> mat <- list(A, B)
> 
> # sum
> Reduce("+", mat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    8    9
[2,]    2    9   15
> 
> # mean
> apply(simplify2array(mat), 1:2, mean)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2  4.0  4.5
[2,]    1  4.5  7.5
```